# How can React read a session SET in PHP

Tags: php, reactjs, session

The form is handed to a php script on the same domain and php creates a session and session values are declared.

I want react to read the session data created by the PHP script

Comment: React can not read the PHP session directly, on its own. You need to make an HTTP request to a PHP script, that returns the data you are interested in.

Comment: How do I do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using cookies instead if security isn't an issue or else try something like this:

session.php

```
<?php session_start(); echo json_encode($_SESSION); ?>
```

code.js

```
fetch('session.php', {credentials: "same-origin"})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: You will need to pass the correct session cookie in order to restore the session though

Comment: my bad.. I usually have session_start() hidden in configs

Comment: Still, not sending the cookie will result in an empty session

Comment: You cannot or should not access the PHP session backend using react.

Comment: @DanielW. any reason why not to?

Comment: @DarkBee if you are running react only in the frontend, there is no way to access the PHP session backend, it's simply not possible. If you are running react/node as frontend+backend, you could technically access the PHP session backend, but nobody does that, think of all the security issues. There is a high chance you do it wrong and leak session data. If you're running two backend languages in the same place this is a weird idea anyways (node + PHP).

Comment: I get that it may not be a good idea to make the entire session readable, but I don't see how its going to be dangerous for allowing read partially or if/when there's nothing sensitive.

Answer (score -1):

Just embed the information you need from PHP in the HTML.

```
<script>
const sessionData = {
    "country": <?= json_encode($intlContext->getCountryCode()); ?>,
    "someSessionValue": <?= json_encode($_SESSION['someValue']); ?>
};
<script>
```

If you cannot read the data from script straight away in react, you can pick them from a meta field:

```
<meta name="country" content="<?= htmlentities($intlContext->getCountryCode()); ?>">
<meta name="someSessionValue" content="<?= htmlentities($_SESSION['someValue']); ?>">
```

There is no need to pass a PHP session ID to react. You cannot verify nor access the session backend from PHP within react.